# Flowplayer in a modal window - control bar and "play" button missing

Tags: css, flowplayer

Can somebody help me with Flowplayer and Prettyphoto?
I want to include Flowplayer in a modal window. For some reason, the modal window shows only video preview but control bar and "play" button don't show up. Any ideas? You tube videos works perfect ion this modal window.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/oth/c/fp/skin/functional.css">
    <script src="/oth/c/fp/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
    <div style="width:450px;height:209px;">
    <div class="flowplayer" data-swf="/oth/c/fp/flowplayer.swf" data-embed="false">
<video>
<source type="video/mp4" src="/video.mp4">
</video>
</div></div>
```

The result with missing control panel: (the white square is reserver for comments, it's not an error).

[image]

Player in a normal webpage:

[image]

Comment: If I call an iframe with Flowplayer from a modal box, everyhing works fine. If I put video directly in the modal box, the control panel is missing. Strange...